# Hyperledger Fabric/Hyperledger Composer Network Definition for a Course Registration Plattform

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I think of creating a blockchain course registration plattform for a "fitness center". I used Hyperledger Composer to go trough the examples, but found no similar example for my purpose:

Every fitness-center member should be able to
- register for a course. 
- take part in several courses (1:n relation).
- delete his attendance
- or transfer his registration of a course to another member of the fitness center

My Question: How would you build a smart design model in Hyperledger Composer with Fabric for my use-case? I made a try here:

My main problem:
Is the design of the 1:n and n:n relations (to fullfil the business network components: Asset/Participants/transactions and Events), that one member has multiple courses and one course could have multiple groups.

As "Assets in Fabric/Composer model" I suggest to be Course and Group (?), but what is about the MatchingCourseToGroup relation and ParticipantsInGroup relation? Where should I place this? Will this be part of the "Business-Logic", written in functions?

As "Participants in Fabric/Composer model" I would place the attendees.

To make clear what I wanna do:
In SQL I would create this tables to build up the relations (Simplified for illustration, *=PrimaryKey):

```
(tbl: Course)
----------------------------------
CourseID* / Name
----------------------------------
001       ; Swim
002       ; Basic Training
003       ; Personal Training Class

(tbl: PersonalData)
----------------------------------
UserID*   / Name            
----------------------------------
1         ; Marc Miller
2         ; Tom Wood  
3         ; Mike Sun 

(tbl: MatchingCourseToGroup)
---------------------------------- 
GroupID*/ CourseID
----------------------------------
A       ;  001 (Group A belongs to the Swim Class)
B       ;  001 (Group B also belongs to the Swim Class)
C       ;  002 (Group C belongs to Basic Training)
D       ;  003 (and so on...) 
E       ;  003
F       ;  003

(tbl: ParticipantsInGroup)
---------------------------------- 
TicketID*/ UserID / CourseID
----------------------------------
01      ; 1 ; A
02      ; 1 ; B
03      ; 1 ; C
04      ; 2 ; A
05      ; 3 ; B
06      ; 3 ; C

Note:
Marc: takes part in 2 swim classes (Course with ID 001, received with primary key A) and (Course with ID 001, received with primary key B).
Other members can also take part in his Course.
```

To come to an end: I'm not really sure if this design as I did it, will be working in the composer, maybe you got some good suggestions for a better design or a similar example.

Cause my next problem will be to make a good privacy implementation and therefore as I understood it, I have to make channels to encapsulate members with read access, change possibilities or to move a member of one group to another one and to reach admin rights.

(Idea is that users can self register them via an tablet at the entrance).

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you need to do, you can try to model your .cto file as follow:

```
namespace org.test

participant Customer identified by customerId {
  o String customerId
  o String firstname
  o String lastname
  --> Course[] enrolledCourses
}

asset Course identified by courseId {
  o String courseId
  o String courseName
  o Integer participants
  o Integer maxParticipants default = 10
  o String status default = "OPEN"
  --> Customer[] participants 
}

transaction courseEnroll {
  --> Customer customer
  --> Course course
}
```

And in your logic js file you can implement the `courseEnroll` transaction by first checking if the course status is still "OPEN". Add the customer to the `participants` array in the Course asset, update the `participants` number and check if the `maxParticipants` number is reached. In this case you can change the status to "Close".

Regarding the access permissions you need to define some rules in a permissions.acl file. You can start for example with this two rules:

```
rule CustomerEnroll {
  description: "Customers can enroll for a course only with their account"
  participant(t): "org.test.Customer"
  operation: ALL
  resource(v): "org.test.courseEnroll"
  condition:  (t.getIdentifier() == v.customer.getIdentifier())
  action: ALLOW
}

rule CustomerSeeUpdateThemselvesOnly {
  description: "Customers can see and update their own record only"
  participant(t): "org.test.Customer"
  operation: READ, UPDATE
  resource(v): "org.test.Customer"
  condition: (t.getIdentifier() == v.getIdentifier())
  action: ALLOW
}
```